# Wordpress custom table query conflict?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am going mad....
I have custom table: wp_wwiz_customers
and among other columns there i have user_status and when I try to update status using wp db query like this:

```
$wpdb->update('wp_wwiz_customers', array( 'user_status' => 'CRAZY' ),array('id' => $entryid)
```

and I am using exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) ); to see response is:

```
string 'UPDATE `wp_wwiz_customers` SET `user_status` = 0 WHERE `id` = '4'' (length=65)
```

Ok, my query seems normal, so why in the world WP puts 0 instead of value.... and I tried to change name of table user_status to user_statusss like in this query and there I have expected result:

```
$wpdb->update('wp_wwiz_customers', array( 'user_statusss' => 'CRAZY' ),array('id' => $entryid)
// Results as:
string 'UPDATE `wp_wwiz_customers` SET `user_statusss` = 'CRAZY' WHERE `id` = '4'' (length=73)
```

Ok, so what is my best bet here ? I just can't change column name right now... is there any option to make this work if this is conflict.... ? ...or maybe I am missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I am again faster to ask than to read documentation....
obviously (sometimes) it is mandatory to place format of data you are entering....

```
$wpdb->update('wp_wwiz_customers', array( 'user_status' => 'CRAZY' ),array('id' => $entryid),array('%s')
```

",array('%s')" part tells WP that this is string... and it works now.